# How to display a the result of a sql query in html?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to display the result of sql query into my web page. I'm using NodeJs for the server side and VueJs, for client side.

I query my database and I have this result :

```
[
  {
    Time_Stamp: 2019-12-09T11:54:00.000Z,
    Time_Stamp_ms: 136,
    CadenceInstant195: 660,
    TempsCycle: 5388,
    Totalisateur195: 0,
    NCPoste1: 87,
    NCPoste2: 2649,
    NCPoste4: 503,
    NCPoste6: 1821,
    NCPoste7: 5590,
    EtatMachine: 0
  },
  {
    Time_Stamp: 2019-12-09T11:55:00.000Z,
    Time_Stamp_ms: 200,
    CadenceInstant195: 660,
    TempsCycle: 5395,
    Totalisateur195: 0,
    NCPoste1: 87,
    NCPoste2: 2649,
    NCPoste4: 503,
    NCPoste6: 1821,
    NCPoste7: 5590,
    EtatMachine: 0
  }
]
```

This result is stocked in a variable in my js file like this :

```
window.onload = function () {
    var consultation = new Vue({
        el:"#consultation",
        data: {
            data : []       
        },
        methods: {
            load: function() {
                this.$http.get("/data?startDate="+this.filtres.startDate+" "+this.filtres.startHour+"&endDate="+this.filtres.endDate+" "+this.filtres.endHour).then(function(response) {
                    this.data = response.body;
                    console.log(this.data);
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The function `load()` throw the query to the database.

My html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <title>Historique</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="consultation">
            {{todos}}
    </div>
    <script src='/AffichageHistorique/js/vue.js'></script>
    <script src='/AffichageHistorique/js/vue-resource.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/AffichageHistorique/js/historique.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to display the result of the query into my web page, but I don't know how. When I write `{{data}}` into my HTML code, it didn't display anything. 
Any idea?

Comment: The problem, I suppose, lies in `this`. Double check what `this` in the callback function refers to and change it to suit your needs.

Comment: @DavidGildour I try to change ```this.data``` in load function and replace it by ```consultation.data```, but it doesn't change a thing

Answer (score 1):

Your result data in the array format, you need to loop the data and bind in HTML.
Use v-for to loop the result data

```
  <ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    {{ item.message }}
  </li>
</ul>

var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    items: [
      { message: 'Foo' },
      { message: 'Bar' }
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: I already try this, but it doesn't work. items isn't recognize

Comment: Have you checked the load method called properly and the response.body object having any data or empty array?

Comment: I think that le load method is called properly and response.body is not empty: I can log it on windows console

Comment: I tried to display my variable todos in my html like this ```{{todos}}``` and I have this error in firefox console : ```uncaught exception: Object``` but with no line indicated

Comment: There may be your component that didn't re-render after the response set to data. Try force update your component After "this.data = response.body;" line using the command "this.$forceUpdate();"

Comment: Can you share your HTML template code, which you used to bind data.

Comment: Of course, I just edit my question. You can go and check

Comment: Can you try the template in the script, `el:"#consultation",
  data: {
    data : []       
  },
  template: "<div>{{data}}</div>"` instead of bind data in HTML page

Comment: It doesn't work, and in bash console I no longer have the json result of the query but only bracket